# How to navigate to current page itself on browser refresh in ionic2?

Tags: angular, routes, ionic2

Iam working on ionic2 project. In that I have login page along with four tabs. At first the login page has to be appear.

For that I have placed

```
rootPage:any = LoginPage
```

for making login page as root page.

It works perfectly. But my problem is on browser refresh,the page reloads and navigated to login page again without staying in current page.

I have changed the root page to current page name and it works perfectly. But I have two modules containing different tabs so for that I cannot give particular tab name in `rootPage`. How can I navigate the page to current page on browser refresh?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are not using lazy loading for your LoginPage at least. So your best bet might be to use the [Deeplinks](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/deeplinks/) Ionic native plugin.

#### Deeplinks

It enables you to use simple routing logic in the form:

```
this.deeplinks.route({
    '/about-us': AboutPage,
    '/universal-links-test': AboutPage,
    '/products/:productId': ProductPage
}).subscribe((match) => {
    // match.$route - the route we matched, which is the matched entry from the arguments to route()
    // match.$args - the args passed in the link
    // match.$link - the full link data
    console.log('Successfully matched route', match);
}, (nomatch) => {
    // nomatch.$link - the full link data
    console.error('Got a deeplink that didn\'t match', nomatch);
});
```

#### Lazy loading

If you can turn your pages into modules, you will automatically have a path for each page in the form of:

```
http://localhost:8100/#/my-page
```

In the [`@IonicPage()`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/IonicPage/) decorator of a page component you can even specify the page's name and the "segment" to use in the URL:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage({
    name: 'customPageName',
    segment: 'custom-path'
})
@Component({
    selector: 'page-device',
    templateUrl: 'device.html',
})
export class MyPage implements OnInit {
    // ...
}
```