# How to Prevent refreshing the page moves to root page in ionic 2/3

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am creating more pages in ionic 2, when i refresh the page it always redirect to the root page index, how to prevent it.

#### Example:

I created login page and welcome page after logging in if i press refresh it automatically moves to root page as login.

Comment: Have you found solution?

Comment: No Bro i dint find the solution @rener172846

Comment: did u find any solution?

Comment: No Bro Still finding a solution for update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a project using **ionic-CLI** usually you have a in **src/app/app-component.ts** a variable called   `rootPage: any = 'HomePage';`

This is your root page. If you want to change to go to your **AuthPage**

```
  rootPage: any = 'AuthPage';
```

Here **AuthPage** is the name of the class of your authpage

Comment: That's for the root page when build is completed, but my doubt is  if i am gonna have login page and welcome page,after i logged in, if i press refresh means its redirecting to rootPage, how to restrict that after logged in bro.....

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is typically observed when you are testing locally (through ionic serve command). I noticed that this should not be the case after deployment to a server. Have you tried doing that and testing it again?

Comment: After i deployed in mobile its working fine, Any how thanks for your response sir.

Answer (score 0):

i've manage to find some solution that solve this problem.

As i know and under my understand the ionic framework use the navcontroller state(push, pop) to navigate the page then if we refresh the browser this navcontroller state will gone and then go to the root.

So the solution that i've found is in this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48662104/how-to-navigate-to-current-page-itself-on-browser-refresh-in-ionic2) from stack overflow also. the answer give you 2 choices "**LazyLoad**" and "**Deeplink**"

But ive manage to solve my solution with "LazyLoad" Method by given custom ionic page segment name that different from the default. for more informantion is [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/IonicPage/)